# How to write GDAL dataset to BytesIO?

Tags: python, io, gdal

I want to save a GDAL dataset to in another library object, but I need to write it first into a BytesIO object in Python.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import io

ds = gdal.Open('path/to/image.tif')
buf = io.BytesIO()

# Save the ds to a bytes object buf
```

How can I save it?

Comment: What do you mean by "to in another library object"? Are you trying to extract the metadata from the image?